# leer localStorage actualizado sin recargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, local-storage

estoy haciendo un boton de dark-mode, el problema es que al darle al boton, ejecuta los 2 case al mismo tiempo siempre, y en el mismo orden, nose que esta mal, o tengo mucho sueño y no encuentro el error en la logica.
Hice el code yo jaja, ayuda!

[image: code]

```
const boton = document.getElementById('dark-mode')
//Codigo para leer el modo actual al iniciar la pagina
let modo = localStorage.getItem('mode')
if(modo === "1" || modo === null){
    light()
}
if(modo === "2"){
    dark()
}
//Evento al acer click en el boton y cambiar el modo
boton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    let modo = localStorage.getItem('mode')
    switch(modo){
        case "1":   
            dark()
            break;
        case "2": 
            light()
            break;
    }
})
//Funciones
function light(){
    console.log("Day") 
    document.getElementById('arriba').style.backgroundColor = "#f"
    localStorage.removeItem('mode')
    localStorage.setItem('mode', "1")
}

function dark(){
    console.log("Night")
    document.getElementById('arriba').style.backgroundColor = "#000"
    localStorage.removeItem('mode')
    localStorage.setItem('mode', "2") 
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido(a) a SOes. El código no debería mostrarse a través de imágenes, recuerda que no todos podemos verlo. Te invito a que [edites](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/560153/edit) tu pregunta y pongas el código con su respectivo formato. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tengas respuestas cuanto antes.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

La lógica no es correcta, porque al hacer clic en el botón no deberías volver a leer el valor, sino tomarlo de la variable e invertirlo, si es 1, hacer que sea 2 para cambiar de claro a oscuro; si es 2, hacer que sea 1 para cambiar de oscuro a claro.

Crea una sola función para analizar el valor, modificar estilos y actualizar localStorage:

```
// Función para establecer el modo
function setMode() {
    if(modo === "1") {
        console.log("Day");
        document.getElementById('arriba').style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    } else {
        // Solo hay dos posibilidades, no es necesario otro if
        console.log("Night");
        document.getElementById('arriba').style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    }
    // Actualizar valor en localStorage, no es necesario eliminar
    localStorage.setItem('mode', modo);
}

const boton = document.getElementById('dark-mode');
// Código para leer el modo actual al iniciar la pagina
// Si no existe en localStorage, se asigna 1 por defecto
let modo = localStorage.getItem('mode') || 1;
// Aplicar cuando se carga la página
setMode();

// Evento al hacer click en el boton y cambiar el modo
boton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Solo hay que cambiar el valor actual de la variable
    if(modo == 1) {
        modo = 2;
    } else {
        modo = 1;
    }
    // Aplicar cambios
});
```

Comment: okey amigo, trataré de realizarla mediante tus indicaciones, gracias por la ayuda!